# Lost GPG private key and revocation certificate

Tags: gnupg, pgp, key

I have created a GPG key and uploaded it to pgp.mit.edu. Then I accidentally wiped the drive that contained both the key and the revocation certificate. So what to do now?

I found a possible answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80550/what-do-i-do-about-a-forgotten-ancient-pgp-key/104133#104133). But how would I do this?

And yes, this time I will keep my private key and revocation certificate safe this time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lost my PGP private key, what's next?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105571/lost-my-pgp-private-key-whats-next)

Comment: I want to do [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80550/what-do-i-do-about-a-forgotten-ancient-pgp-key/104133#104133). But I don't know how.